# Why does the BadDataFound handler get called 2 times for 1 bad record?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I wired up the `BadDataFound` handler for my `CsvHelper` configuration.

```cs
csvConfig.BadDataFound = args =>
{
    _output.WriteLine($"BadDataFound: {args.Field}...");
};
```

Sample CSV (abbreviated):

```
case|unique_id|record
1731030|1|"{"apiversion\":\"1.0\",\"zone\":\"west\"}"
1478634|1|"{\"apiversion\":\"1.0\",\"zone\":\"north\"}"
```

The test file I'm trying out has 1 bad record where the quoted field is missing an escape. When I write a log message or set a break point I see that the handler is being called 2 times for this 1 bad record.

```
BadDataFound: "{"apiversion\":\"1.0\",\"zone\":\"west\"}"
BadDataFound: "{"apiversion\":\"1.0\",\"zone\":\"west\"}"
```

The quote before apiversion is missing the escape but only 1 record has this problem.

This will lead to me logging the issue twice.

Why does this handler fire 2 times? Is there a configuration option that controls this behavior?

Comment: I don't understand the sample data you posted; are you trying to parse json as a csv?

Comment: Yes, the CSV data does have embedded JSON in one of the fields. I'll update my question with a sample.

Comment: Could it be because there are two issues with this single record, **1)** `"{"` isn't valid JSON, and **2)** the record contains extra data: `apiversion\":\"1.0\",\"zone\":\"west\"}"`

Comment: @rfmodulator Interesting. That's a great clue! I'll try a simplified example without JSON and see if I can confirm that.

Comment: I changed the record to `1731030|1|""123"` (extra quote) and now the event BadDataFound handler fires 3 times. Very strange. I'll run some more experiments and try to narrow it down. I think the solution either way it just to check the list I'm saving bad records into and skipping the ones I have already. I may not find a way to control how many times this handlers runs.

Comment: @MatthewMacFarland I'm not very familiar with `CsvHelper`, I've used it once I think... does `args` contain a row and column index of where the bad data was found... if so, you could use that to get a distinct list of problematic rows. Or perhaps there is a better callback for this purpose? Or a "fail on first error" configuration option?

Comment: @rfmodulator I'm also new to CsvHelper but it seems like a very nice choice for .NET apps. Yes, the bad data found args has many details like row and column position. Using the debugger I compared them as carefully as possible between each occurrence of the bad data found error and I could not find any differences at all. Same row, field, column, everything. I have not found config options yet to control this but I'm still learning this library so hopefully I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I was just thinking, since you are using pipe "|" for your delimiter, I think you could get away with `CsvMode.Escape`.  *However*, you would run into issues if your JSON data contains either the "|" or a newline character.

```cs
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = "|",
        Escape = '\\',
        Mode = CsvMode.Escape
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("case|unique_id|record\n1731030|1|\"{\"apiversion\\\":\\\"1.0\\\",\\\"zone\\\":\\\"west\\\"}\""))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {      
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    [Name("case")]
    public int Case { get; set; }
    [Name("unique_id")]
    public int UniqueId { get; set; }
    [Name("record")]
    public string Record { get; set; }
}
```

**Regarding the BadDataFound issue**

Unfortunately, I believe this is a bug.  It was reported by someone else on 10/5/2021.  https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1873

A second user, craigc39, had a potential hacky solution for his issue with it.

> There is definitely a way around this - but it's incredibly hacky. You would have to use the CSV Helper library twice - once to scan the CSV and record the bad rows - including the exact row number where they happen. That way, when you are generating your bad rows list, you can ensure that there are no duplicates. Second time using the CSV Library to read all the rows - and skip any rows that you recorded in bad rows in the scan. That way, the bad rows don't actually end up going into the good rows. I'm about to test out this solution and hoping it works.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I've had pretty good results so far by checking my bad records list each time the bad data found event fires. If it already has the row in the list then I skip it. Seems to work fine. Mixing JSON and CSV makes things more complex. I'm not surprised the parser has some trouble with that case. The source data has variable columns in that "record" field so they used JSON to get the flexibility. Maybe JSON all the way would have been easier.

Comment: I updated my answer slightly since I don't think I had the problem data correct the first time.  I didn't change the answer much. I just had to add the `Escape` character of "\". `CsvMode.Escape` could still work.